# Customized Sort and remove double quotes join by underscore of multiple columns from tab delimited file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, python, csv

***Custom Sort based on subject column order should be Maths, English, Science***

 when I use this below command

```
awk -F',' '{if (NR!=1) {print $2,$3,$5,$4}}' myfile.csv
```

on my *myfile.csv* I am getting like this but I want some other way

```
"101"    "Anna"    "Maths"    "V"
"102"    "Bob"    "Maths"    "V"
"103"    "Charles"    "Science"    "VI"
"104"    "Darwin"    "Science"    "VI"
"105"    "Eva"    "English"    "VII"
```

***sort based on subject column order should be Maths, English, Science***
removed double quotes and joined by underscore
like this

```
101_Anna_Maths_V
102_Bob_Maths_V
105_Eva_English_VII
103_Charles_Science_VI
104_Darwin_Science_VI
```

**Original file: output of `cat myfile.csv`**

```
Sl.No,RollNo,Names,Class,Subject
1,101,Anna,V,Maths
2,102,Bob,V,Maths
3,103,Charles,VI,Science
4,104,Darwin,VI,Science
5,105,Eva,VII,English
```

Comment: it would be better if you also post original input, so that it is easier to test

Comment: posting image is no help to test either, how would one copy it to file? and neither does it show how it is saved in text format... copy paste output of `cat myfile.csv`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original command:

```
awk -F',' '{if (NR!=1) {print $2,$3,$5,$4}}' myfile.csv
```

Your command written in the idiomatic `awk` way:

```
awk -F',' 'NR > 1 { print $2, $3, $5, $4 }' myfile.csv
```

Above command, modified to remove all double quotes for every line of input for which `NR > 1`:

```
awk -F',' 'NR > 1 { gsub(/"/, ""); print $2, $3, $5, $4 }' myfile.csv
```

Above command, modified to output with `_` as the output field separator (`OFS`):

```
awk -F',' -vOFS='_' 'NR > 1 { gsub(/"/, ""); print $2, $3, $5, $4 }' myfile.csv
```

Comment: Love the step by step discovery of the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since question is revised, use below `sed` solution for given input to get

1. Swiping fields #4 and #5
2. Remove first field
3. Replace commas with Underscore
4. skip first line as header

```
sed -r '2,$s/^[^,]*,// ; 2,$s/^([^,]*,[^,]*)(,[^,]*)(.*)/\1\3\2/ ; 2,$s/,/_/g'
```

---

Using `sed`.

```
sed 's/"//g;s/[[:space:]]\+/_/g;/^$/d' infile
```

- `s/"//g` This removes all quotes `"`.
- `[[:space:]]\+` This replace one-or-more whitespaces with single Underscore `_`.
- `/^$/d` This removes empty lines, you can remove it from the command if you don't have any. or change with `/^[[:space:]]*$/d` to remove lines with Spaces/Tabs/Empty only.

Replace `\+` with the standard `\{1,\}` equivalent if your `sed` implementation doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **awk** solution for comma-separated input file(according to your `-F','`):

```
awk -v FPAT='[^",[:space:]]+' 'NR>1{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i<NF)?OFS:ORS }' OFS='_' myfile.csv
```

The output:

```
01_Anna_Maths_V
102_Bob_Maths_V
103_Charles_Science_VI
104_Darwin_Science_VI
105_Eva_Maths_VII
```